# Shared emacs session without shared user accounts

Tags: emacs, multi-user

I am currently working in a group, editing latex files for submission.  With multiple people editing the same file, and with many unrelated changes for grammar or phrasing, using a repository would not work, because every pull would require merging changes in by hand.  Since we are all familiar with emacs, we would like to have a shared session, in which we can all edit the file.

I know that this is possible if we are on the same user account, either through `M-x make-frame-on-display` or by using `emacs --daemon` and `emacsclient`.  However, to the best of my knowledge, these would require either a shared user account, which we do not have permissions to make, or one of us to provide access to our personal account, which would not be good practice.

Is there a way to share an emacs session without sharing a user account?

Comment: Slightly different approach: Use something like [Floobits](https://floobits.com/) or [Rudel](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Rudel) for [collaborative editing](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollaborativeEditing).

Comment: Consider using [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I had considered tmux, but I was under the impression that while we could then have a shared emacs session, we would not be able to edit the same file at the same time, because only one person could be "driving" the session.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, because of the power of Emacs, to give access to someone at one's Emacs is effectively to give him access to one's account.

Still there is severall way (supposing you are under some unix or linux):

- For M-x make-frame-on-display to work, you only need to authorize the the other host to have access to you display

  - `xauth list` will list the MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE of your display you can then give to your friend for them to send you a frame on your display using `make-frame-on-display`. You cannot ungive the COOKIE, but a new one is generated if you logout then login.
  - `xhost +` will remove all access control. So if you are in a place than can be trusted, you can temporarily do `xhost +` to accept the frame, then `xhost -` will add access control back. `xhost +foo` and `xhost -foo` will do the same only for the host `foo`
- You can configure your emacs server to accept connection over tcp, using the variable `emacs-use-tcp`.

All this being said, the security implication of all this are complex. Using Floobits or Rudel as chris proposed seem to me a far better solution.